# Ejecutar php cada cierto tiempo sin ajax

Tags: php

Buen día!!!
Tengo una duda, hay forma de hacer que una función se ejecute en ciertos horarios pero sin ajax? Me explico, tengo que hacer una petición a una web con un web service, el tema está que no se pueden hacer más de 100 consultas diarias, pasa que la página se debe recargar más veces por día, porque es una aplicación web multiusuario, entonces pensé, que cada cierta hora se haga la consulta y la guarde en la base de datos. Debe ser sin ajax, ya que ajax se ejecuta si la página está andando, y es necesario que se consulte al web service desde el host sin que este on la página..  Espero haber sido claro en la consulta.. desde ya mil gracias !!

Comment: Tal vez, para tu caso, puedas usar cron.

Comment: péganos un ejemplo de la petición que debes hacer al webservice (método, url, tipo de credencial, datos y respuesta esperada).

Comment: Con cron jobs podrías lograrlo.

Comment: Hola @amenadiel, mira, tengo esta pagina, http://estadisticasbcra.com/api/documentacion, es sobre la cotización del dólar, aún no me puse con el código, sólo me surgió esa duda para ya atacarla desde temprano.

Comment: Hola @track3r... Que sería cron? No hace mucho que estoy con php

Comment: Hay muchas formas de hacer lo que quieres. Cuando te conectas a una WEB haces una petición HTTP/S al servidor que te devuelve el HTML correspondiente. AJAX te permite hacer peticiones asincronas al servidor que te hacen transparente el efecto de "recargar la página". Así como puedes usar un cliente en JS para hacer consultas a tu API puedes buscar cientos clientes alternativos para hacer peticiones HTTP/S desde cualquier plataforma y/o lenguaje. Lo unico que tendrías que hacer es programar las consultas que necesitas y hacer un script que ejecute tu cliente cada x tiempo o bien hacer un progra

Comment: Cron es un servicio del sistema en linux. No tiene nada que ver con PHP. Puedes programar la ejecución de tareas arbitrariamente

Comment: Ahí estuve averiguando, debería ver en Windows con task mánager, para probar, y después programar la tarea desde el hora... Son unos genios!!!! Gracias!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ver... la idea sería que tuvieras el código andando para poder decirte cómo ejecutarlo usando un cronjob, pero ni siquiera tienes el código andando así que vamos a trabajar con una maqueta.

Dado que:

- tienes un endpoint (e.g. `http://api.com/endpoint`)
- un token (e.g. `080042cad6356ad5dc0`)
- el API espera un token de tipo Bearer
- el API responde con JSON

Puedes usar curl para traerte los datos. Digamos que el siguiente script se llama "**trae_datos.php**":

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

$headers = [
    'Content-Type: application/json', 
    'Authorization: Bearer 080042cad6356ad5dc0'
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.com/endpoint');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$respuesta = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$resultado = json_decode($respuesta, true);
```

Ese script php puede encargarse de insertar el resultado en la base de datos (acá estoy instanciando una conexión con una clase inventada e insertando con un método inventado:

```
<?php

$conexion = new TipoDeConexion($usuario, $password, $host,  $pulpos_pegajosos);

... petición curl...

insertaResultado($resultado);
```

Ese script ya hace todo lo que necesitas, sólo tienes que correrlo **por línea de comando** como:

```
php trae_datos.php
```

En vez de ejecutarlo durante el ciclo de un request generado por ajax o por otra petición desde el frontend.

Para automatizar la ejecución del script, lo pones en un cron, ejecutando:

`crontab -e`

La estructura del archivo crontab es:

```
  m         h        dom       mon          dow            command
(minuto) (hora) (dia_del_mes) (mes) (dia_de_la_semana) (comando a ejecutar)
```

Así que si quieres ejecutar tu script todos los días a las 9:30 AM le añadirías al cron una línea que contenga:

```
30 9 * * * cd /home/gals/proyecto && /usr/bin/php trae_datos.php >> datos.log
```

Donde `30 9 * * *` significa "todos los días a las 9:30 AM sin importar en qué mes estamos, ni en qué día del mes ni en qué día de la semana".

El resto es decirle que navegue hasta el directorio donde está el script y luego lo ejecute. Nótese que estoy usando `/usr/bin/php` porque el cron no siempre tiene acceso a tu PATH y es mejor darle la ruta completa. Finalmente, mando la salida (cualquier `echo` ejecutado en el script) a `datos.log`. Esto es un paso opcional pero lo vas a necesitar si un día no tienes datos frescos y quieres saber qué falló.

Comment: Gracias Genio!!!!!!!!!!! me funcionó perfecto!!! Gracias!!!